# Error creating bean with name 'appUserService' defined in class path resource: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0

Tags: java, spring, security, registration, spring-bean

When I compile my spring project, I got the following error.

> Error creating bean with name 'appUserService' defined in file [K:\ChessGE JAVA\ChessGe\target\classes\com\example\chessge\appuser\AppUserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'appUserRepository' defined in com.example.chessge.appuser.AppUserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ChessGeApplication: Not a managed type: class com.example.chessge.appuser.AppUser

There is my code:
AppUser:

```
package com.example.chessge.appuser;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AppUser implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "student_sequence",
            sequenceName = "student_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "student_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AppUserRole appUserRole;
    private Boolean locked = false;
    private Boolean enabled = false;

    public AppUser(String firstName,
                   String lastName,
                   String email,
                   String password,
                   AppUserRole appUserRole) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.appUserRole = appUserRole;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority =
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority(appUserRole.name());
        return Collections.singletonList(authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !locked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

AppUserRepository:

```
package com.example.chessge.appuser;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, Long> {
    Optional<AppUser> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

AppUserService:

```
package com.example.chessge.appuser;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AppUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE = "User %s not found";
    private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return appUserRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(()->
                new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE,email)));
    }
}
```

I've already tried to add

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.chessge.appuser")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.chessge.appuser")
```

to the ChessGeApplication but it didn't help.

Comment: what `@ EntityScan` are you using? can you add full import for it

Answer (score 0):

In `AppUserService` the field `AppUserRepository` should be marked as `@Autowired` as in:

```java
@Autowired
private AppUserRepository appUserRepository;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: unfortunatelty it didn't help :/

Comment: The error is the same?

Comment: yes, it is the same

Comment: https://wesome.org/spring-data-jpa-enablejparepositories explains this situation where we can organize the db structure for entities and repositories, i.e. one package for the entities and another one for the repositories.

Comment: i forgot to add that i have also this class:

Comment: That's ok, you can edit the original question and add the WebSecurityConfig there. But I think the code it's ok. I would suggest deleting both annotations (@EntityScan and @EnableJpaRepositories) and instead create a folder named db where inside you can create 2 folders: entity and repository. Put the AppUser in entity and the AppUserRepository in repository. Also make sure that the Main class has the @SpringBootApplication annotation in order to enable the components scan.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.chessge.security.config;

import com.example.chessge.appuser.AppUserService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final AppUserService appUserService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        //http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        return (web) -> auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(appUserService);
        return provider;
    }
}
```